# zero vector subspace

Tags: vector-spaces

Does a zero vector by itself constitute a subspace?
It appears to satisfy all 3 conditions.

1. Contains zero
2. Hold under addition
3. Holds under scalar multiplication

Can any other single vector do that?

Comment: Clearly, any other single vector can't satisfy the first axiom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is called the trivial vector space. No other vector can do that because any vector space must have a zero vector. (so if it contains only one vector then it must be the zero vector)